# Android Pay from my app

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I want to make payment from my android application. I am confused with In App Purchase, In App Billing, Android Pay API and third party libraries like pay pal etc.

Are these payment gateways ?

```
1) In App Purchase 
2) In App Billing 
3) Android Pay API
```

What is the different between them ? and what should i use ?

i read on stack overflow. Now google do not permits to use any third party library for making payments. is it true ?

Please help me with above queries.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in App purchase and in App billing are the same thing. They are used for purchases made within the App - for example, I have written a simple game where the first 6 levels are free, but if you want to play the higher levels you have to purchase them and my App has it coded within it, using the Google Play API. They are not used for payments for anything outside of the Apps.

Comment: what are payment gateways ? Are they different ?

Comment: Yes. A payment gateway is a way of paying for something, like paypal or a credit card. While it is true that a payment gateway is used for in-app purchases, the two are different. Generally, an in-app purchase is charged to the person logged into Google Play on that device.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use payment method with you android application then you can use payment gateway like paypal, stripe etc.., Google provide new way to payment that is android pay it provide credit card authentication .

I am mentioning following steps these may be useful for you.

Step 1:- If you are not in us and you want to use android pay then you should have a us registered email id (You can make us email id with help of gmail ) then you can download android pay .

Step2: You can register you credit card in android pay now a days few credit cards are supported by android pay you can try with Visa, Master Card, American Express cards and other cards which support the android pay.

Step 3: Implement following points https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams .

If you have some problem then comment me.